# Deleting files in an array in ruby

Tags: ruby, file, delete-file

I want to delete all the files of a certain type that come up in an array. Code is as follows:

```
Dir['**/*.???']
```

I tried `File.delete`, but could not figure out how to pass the array. I was thinking something like:

```
Dir['**/*.???'].each do|i|
  File.delete(something?)
end
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you only want to delete files (not directories). This will find files in subdirectories as well.

```
Dir['**/*.???'].reject{|i| File.directory?(i) }.each{ |i| File.delete(i) }
```

It finds all files that are children/descendents of the current directory, filters out any directories, and then deletes.

Comment: Thats the idea, but I would like to get all directories

Comment: I see - updated answer. Will find all files in all subdirectories.

Answer (score 2):

You can do

```
require 'fileutils'

FileUtils.rm Dir.glob('**/*.???')
```

[`::rm`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/fileutils/rdoc/FileUtils.html#method-c-rm)

> Remove file(s) specified in list. This method cannot remove directories. All StandardErrors are ignored when the :force option is set.